# Prevent the back button from quitting android app inside a Cordova plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am creating a Cordova plugin based on the Android Camera2Video example: 
http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Video/index.html

My plugin code is working here:
https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom

When I press the Android back button within the WebView I can successfully control it's behaviour using the following JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert('back pressed');
}, false);
```

However when I press the same back button while the native plugin overlay is shown, the JavaScript is ignored and the app quits.

How can I catch the back button event and use it to trigger my plugin hide() method?

Here is a link to the Cordova code handling the JavaScript back button:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4bf705a3d39b34400388265381a9975b246e3779/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CoreAndroid.java#L231
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/4bf705a3d39b34400388265381a9975b246e3779/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, override the method `onBackPressed()`. It is called when user taps on Back  button.

Comment: I tried this in my file here but it didn't catch it?
https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom/blob/master/src/android/MediaCustom.java

Comment: This example has it, but doesn't seem to work for me: https://github.com/gazeing/rebBackUp/blob/0f261da8ef93ba7379e29c70df8efd33febe840c/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java

Comment: onBackPressed is method of Activity class, so you have to override it in your activity, not in MediaCustom class.

Comment: I tried adding a MainActivity.class but it doesn't seem to be making a difference: https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom/blob/master/src/android/MainActivity.java maybe it's not being loaded?

Comment: Did you start this activity? Is activity visible when you press the back button? What is a base class of CordovaActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You could override onBackPressed and instead call your plugin's method.

Comment: I tried it inside my Plugin method here but it didn't work: https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom/blob/master/src/android/MediaCustom.java

Comment: This example uses the method you describe, but it doesn't work for me: https://github.com/gazeing/rebBackUp/blob/0f261da8ef93ba7379e29c70df8efd33febe840c/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java

Comment: I've also tried adding as a MainActivity.java file with the method, but it doesn't seem to be loaded: https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom/blob/master/src/android/MainActivity.java

Comment: I found this example: https://github.com/weconstudio-it/phonegap-plugin-backbuttonreset/blob/2a5ebeff1f151cb9ccfe474023363d4bb131c2e3/src/it/weconstudio/phonegap/plugins/android/BackButtonReset.java but it doesn't work for me